# addScript function does not work when I load website the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use `jquery.flexslider` plugin, which works fine.

But for screens < 600px I do not want to load the plugin. I tried several scripts and ended with the following, which I thought works best.

I inserted it after the CSS and the JS tags in the header, but unfortunately it works only on second load, not on the first neither with F5 (tested in IE 11 and in Chrome 45.0.2454.101).

```
function addScript (src) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = 'www.mywebadre.ss/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js'; 
  document.head.appendChild(script);
} 

if (screen.width > 600) {
  addScript("www.mywebadre.ss/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js");
}
```

See http://tinyurl.com/qjkeesg

Comment: So you only care about checking the screen width on the initial load of the page?

Comment: I guess you're trying to hide a slideshow for smaller screens,  If that is the case then I'd recommend forgetting what you're trying to do and use css media queries to show/hide relevant elements.

Comment: I wonder why your function addScript has a in parameter `src` if you don't use it

Comment: yes I'm trying to hide a slideshow for smaller screens,

Answer (score 0):

Because of cross-browser differences, you cannot always rely upon document.head already being there. Use document.getElementsById instead to get a reference to the element.

```
function addScript(src) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = src;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
if (screen.width > 600) {
    addScript('http://www.mywebadre.ss/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js');
}
```

Also, I noticed that you were not using http or https on the front of the URL.

After testing this out, it does work in IE and in Chrome so long as I use a valid URL. As a last step, make sure that your URL is valid by pasting it into a browser.

Comment: thanks - I tried your script but same as before - flexslider-min loads only if I go to URL and click return, with F5 nothing happens.

Comment: there is no error - jquery.flexslider-min.js only loads if I load the site the second time

Comment: Well, I did also notice that you were not adding the "http" to the URL, so I updated the code. I bet it is an IE thing because this works in my other browsers.

Comment: In my original script I used http

Comment: The only thing I can guess is that the URL you are pointing to is not being resolved. The above code, albeit with any other URL for a script reference, works in Chrome and even in IE 8 when I test it. Make sure that your URL is actually valid by pasting it into the address bar of one of your browsers.

Comment: Is there a possibilty to run jquery.flexslider-min.js if media Screen >600 as top priority JavaScript instead of last?                                                         document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help, finally I found a solution by myself:

there is no seperate script needed for adding external script in Connection
 with Screen.width

simply open the jquery.flexslider-min.js and add to the beginning
of the originally script as follow :

```
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 500px)" );
if (mq.matches) {   here is the original code, just let it how it is }
```

Don't Forget the **}** at the end of original script to close again. hope I
can help others with this simple trick
 mona